# Access img style with css by grandparent div title tag how to?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having trouble with accessing img css created by wordpress plugin,

I tried something like this and it doesn't work.

```
div.wpls-fix-box [title="dolce gusto capsule"] > div > img
{
  width:200px !important;
}
```

Only thing that separates slider images is the title tag so I need to use that in order to avoid decreasing all images width in slider.

Can someone help please, thanks !

```
<div class="wpls-logo-cnt slick-slide slick-active" title="dolce gusto capsule" data-slick-index="3" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 444px;" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-describedby="slick-slide13">    
<div class="wpls-fix-box">
        <img class="wp-post-image" src="http://sccaffe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/dolcegustocapsuletransparent.png" alt="">     

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working :S , thanks for trying to help tho

Comment: sorry, it should only be `[title="dolce gusto capsule"] > div > img` (https://jsfiddle.net/jmfxtqsh/2/)

Comment: yea, working now ! thanks a lot :D